# lm311 and optoisolator producing error when simulation is run

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, opto-isolator

i have the following setup. the goal is to turn off the LED when the LM311 output is high and turn on the LED when the LM311 output is low. The LED of the optoisolator that is.
[image]

On my software Proteus, when the LM311 is high, it works. But, when it is low, it gives several errors.

The software tends to be buggy sometimes and its hard to debug since the community for it is small, but is there anything wrong with the schematic?
[image]

edit: here's a better picture
[image]

Comment: What is that `D1` doing? What's driving it? Try adding a `1meg` resistor to ground after it. It might not matter, but you conncted both a `250` Ohm `R1` and the diode in parallel with the `10.5k` of `R15`. Can you show the whole schematic, but without the spaghetti look? (aka please draw those wires so that they are readable, don't force people to decipher something that should be trivial)

Comment: i put a diode to both inputs of the lm311 because i was getting some sort of reverse voltage from one input through the lm311 and back into the other input. the negative terminal is coming from a DC generator, the other is from Vref. the Vdc is being compared with Vref to drive the output of the optoisolator. the circuit is powered by a 12V DC source. R1 reduces the current for the LED of the optoisolator to its drive current range. I will add a larger schema.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the simplest circuit which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LM311](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf?ts=1623459639399&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.co.nz%252F) has PNP transistors on its inputs.

[image]

You have coupled the inputs through diodes that block the input bias current they need to operate. You should remove the diodes, and if the bias current upsets the input voltages then reduce the resistor values in your voltage dividers so it has less effect (eg. change 30.1k to 3.01k etc.).

Comment: Gotta let those bias currents flow

Comment: brilliant! without the diodes though, i was having some problems with the input + and - voltages not being the value they should be (being off by 10%), so i naively though that the diodes there would solve everything (and it did). but without them right now, im within 1 percent surprisingly so its okay. what do you recommend if the the input + and - are imprecise later on? i guess i should study the IC schema more though!

Comment: Bias current produces a voltage across the source resistance. Both inputs should have similar bias current, so if the source resistances are similar (as yours are) both inputs should be 'imprecise' by about the same amount and the comparison will still be 'accurate'. Bias current offset and source resistance imbalance reduce accuracy. Max bias current on the LM311 is 250nA @25ºC, which produces ~7.5mV across 30.1k. If you reduce the resistances to 3.01k then the 'error' should be less than 0.75mV. But even 7.5mV is probably fine because the bias _offset_ should be much smaller.

Comment: thanks so much. i have been trying to wrap my head around this all day and i think i am getting it. but for the diode, can you explain how it pertains to coupling (as in transfer of energy i think)? diodes just restrict current from flowing in the opposite direction right? so it should act as a short in the direction its pointing. but is it unnecessarily increasing current flow thereby deactivating the PNP transistor when instead the collector and emitter should be shorted?